# Soap Web Service Client Add multiple header elements Apache Axis

Tags: soap, apache-axis

I m using Apache Axis to generate the web service client. 
I need to add multiple header elements in request. Please find the Soap UI request body below.

```
   <soap:Header>
      <token xmlns="test">12345</token>
      <idnum xmlns="test">true</idnum>
      <login xmlns="test">5678</login>
      <issuer xmlns="test">welcome</issuer>
   </soap:Header>
```

Can you please guide me a way to do it. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get SOAPHeader from SOAPEnvelope (and SOAPEnvelope you can get from MessageContext).

Then you can add SOAPHeaderBlock, OMAttribute or a child element to SOAPHeader. I'm not sure which one you need for your request.

There are other overloaded methods you can use for creation of beforementioned elements, so feel free to experiment. Below example is surely far from perfect as I didn't have to do many of such modifications to the headers thus I'm not experienced. I had however did a bit some time ago so please use this example as a starting point to explore deeper.

```
public void addHeaders(MessageContext msgContext) {
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = msgContext.getEnvelope();
        SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
        // adding HeaderBlock
        header.addHeaderBlock(new QName("http://some.name.space","localPartName"));
        // adding OMAttribute
        OMAttributeImpl omAttribute = new OMAttributeImpl();
        omAttribute.setAttributeType("type_of_attribute");
        omAttribute.setAttributeValue("some_value");
        omAttribute.setOMNamespace(new OMNamespaceImpl("http://some.uri", "somePrefix"));
        header.addAttribute(omAttribute);
        // add a child created with OMFactory
        OMNamespace omNamespace = new OMNamespaceImpl("http://some.other.uri", "someOtherPrefix");
        OMElement element = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory().createOMElement("sth", omNamespace);
        element.addAttribute("attr1", "attr1_Value", omNamespace);
        element.addAttribute("attr2", "attr2_Value", omNamespace);
        header.addChild(element);
    }
```